# How to use the validation method?

Tags: arrays

Hi i made a portal for institute and now need to use validation method so username cannot be repeated at the time of registration. So how to use array list in validate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check all records of table if you use array list for check repeated username instead of this use

"select * from table_name where username='pass the string that user enter for user name'"

You can get only one row if that user name exist so it will reduce your code.

If it's not repeated then returning row will be zero so you can easily check this by simple if and else condition.